Using Session Cookie to skip MFA Orchestration Step
I want to use the sso cookie to disable MFA via email, after user pressed on "keep me signed in", entered email and password and verified once via email.
Following the docu
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-a-relying-party-file
keepAliveInDays
I can addjust keep alive days and the expiration date of the sso cookie changes accordingly
SSO-Cookie Expiration Date
If the user does not click on "keep me signed in" there will be also a sso cookie but without expiration date.
However, I'm using a verification step which I want to skip if there is this cookie with expiration date
<OrchestrationStep Order="9" Type="ClaimsExchange">
            <Preconditions>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>isActiveMFASession</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>
              <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
                <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>              
            </Preconditions>
            <ClaimsExchanges>
              <ClaimsExchange Id="EmailFactor-Verify" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOTPUsingEmailAddress" />
            </ClaimsExchanges>
          </OrchestrationStep>

I was thinking about another precondition claim
<Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                <Value>isPersistedSession</Value>
                <Value>true</Value>
                <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
              </Precondition>

But have no idea how this claim is derrived from the sso cookie

true = if existing, valid and not expired
false = if expired, invalid or no expiration date is defined

Followed the docu on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-a-relying-party-file but there is no information how to skip MFA.
Without MFA it works but this is a nogo for security reasons.
Any recommendations how to implement this precondition correctly?

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
